# using Machine.protect to encrypt values into sql server with EF

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-5

I am looking at leveraging the MachineKey API in .net 4.5 to encrypt values into SQL Server through EF

```
     public static string Protect(string text, string purpose)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return null;

        byte[] stream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        var encodedValue = MachineKey.Protect(stream, purpose);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(encodedValue);
    }

    public static string Unprotect(string text, string purpose)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return null;

        byte[] stream = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
        byte[] decodedValue = MachineKey.Unprotect(stream, purpose);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedValue);
    }
```

So I have an helper class as above and I call it below

```
        using (ContactEntities ctx = new ContactEntities())
        {
            Account newaccounts = new Account();

            newaccounts.AccountType = EncrytionHelper.Protect("current","cipher");
            ctx.Accounts.Add(newaccounts);
            ctx.SaveChanges();

        }
```

However, I get an entityvalidation error on the ctx.SaveChages() line

Any ideas please.

Thanks

Comment: What does the error **say**?

Comment: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: And what does the exception's EntityValidationErrors property say?

Comment: It just throws that generic error no futher information.... I am using nvarchar(max) datatype the encypted value generated is of this length 1fBIjTDHDStvd0RExrqnPw+VgIZ303K7VrU+NIDK78AAD00ue5iiZhG5YymRGuGtXxfQ1VHeU/ijbaEwgtMSoQ==.If I shorten the string generated and inserted directly using EF,it works well. I reckon this is a data length issues...

Comment: Entity of type "Account" in state "Added" has the following validation errors:- Property: "AccountType", Error: "The field AccountType must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '50'."This field uses Nvachar(250) already